# Does Pact net supports application/json-patch+json content type?

Tags: pact, pact-net

I am currently not able to create contracts for the API calls that takes JsonPatchDocument object as body in PATCH request. Although I tried to build the body (JsonPatchDocument) using ExpandoObject Pact is considering the body content type as application/json only.

Can someone please help? looks none of our services that has got JsonPatchDocument object can be tested.

Comment: Could you share some code? How are you defining your assumptions? Have you tried using `.WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json")`?

Comment: Thank you @StefanGolubović for your reply. I have received confirmation from pact team that the support is not available for this content-type and this is considered as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Pact should support this content type (it's still valid JSON, it's just a specific shape). If it doesn't, it's a bug and should be fixed.